# RaspberyPI connected drone controller

Tags: raspberry-pi, controller, dronekit

I am searching for drone controller that can be connected with RaspberyPI, can you please recommend good ones? And do I also need to check that the controller is compatible with other parts of the drone (battery, motors, etc.)? If so, how?

Thanks for answering.